# Do Until Loop InputBox infinitely loops

Tags: vba, excel, probability

I am creating a probability macro where user enters number of players in a card game. If I enter string (ex, `Joe`), non-integer(ex, `15.67`), or integer less than 0 (ex, `-25`), the InputBox should loop. However, integers greater than 0 should terminate the loop. (I have to force kill Excel to stop the InputBox regardless of user input.)

I want the InputBox to close / Exit Sub once an integer greater than 0 is entered. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Sub GenerateCards()
Players = InputBox("How many players? Please enter an integer.")
    Do Until TypeName(Players) = "Integer" And Players > 0 ' why does this loop even if both conditions are met (ex, Players=5?)
        Players = InputBox("How many players? Please enter an integer.")
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InputBox()` always returns a string, so `TypeName()` will always return `"String"`.

But you *can* test if the string that's returned is an integer. First, you can use `IsNumeric()` to test if the string is a numeric value. Then, you can safely cast it to a `Double` or an `Integer`. In fact, you can cast it to both and then compare them against each other. If they're the same, you've got an integer value. For example:

```
Sub GenerateCards()

    Do
        Players = InputBox("How many players? Please enter an integer.")

        If IsNumeric(Players) Then
            If CDbl(Players) = CLng(Players) And Players > 0 Then
                ' Integer > 0 entered. Exit loop...
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this with some strings, decimals, and various integers.

Comment: OK, I tried this, it works flawlessly in all run-time instances. Thanks!