# How do I insert an input box that will ask for a date and then add to Rows after that date?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub date
    Dim DTE as Date
    MBox = InputBox(“Enter Friday date”)
    If IsDate(MBox) Then
        DTE = CDate(MBox)
        Range(“F” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
     Else 
         MsgBox(“This isn’t a date. Try again.”)
    End if
End sub
```

I need the code to add two rows after it finds the date the user enters in the input box and then add up the values in column D. I realize the range row is incorrect but I am not sure how to insert the rows after the date I entered.

Comment: You will want to use the `Range.Find` method most likely, but this is highly dependent on the formats being correct. On the spreadsheet, do the dates have time stamps or is the decimal 0?

Comment: Also, you cannot name a sub `date` as this is reserved word

Comment: They are not time stamped and when I put range.find, it comes up as an error “argument not optional.”

Comment: Working on solution - hold steady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things

1. You cannot name your sub `date` as this is a reserved word
2. No need for `.Selection`
3. If you use `Application.Inputbox`, you can control the input type (*to some degree*)

---

*Assumes you are working on `Sheet1` and your dates that are to be matched against the user input span `Column F`*

```
Sub Date_Finder()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
Dim xInput As Date, Found As Range

xInput = Application.InputBox("Enter Date [mm/dd/yyyy]", Type:=1)

    If IsDate(xInput) Then
        Set Found = ws.Range("F:F").Find(xInput)

        If Found Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Input not found in range"
        Else
            Found.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert (xlShiftDown)
            Found.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert (xlShiftDown)                
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Entry. Ending sub" & vbNewLine & "Entry: " & xInput, vbCritical
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How would I add a sum function to the first empty row I after the data and adding everything above it up to cell D4?

Comment: That is a completely different question. Give it some time to try to figure that out - if you cant, new questions get new posts. If this answered the question in your initial post, you should accept the solution :)

Comment: This finds the first cell that contains a date I enter. How do I modify it to come from bottom up instead of top down?

Comment: You can amend options on the `Range.Find` method. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) link will tell you exactly how

Comment: How do I get this to where if the date is not found, it will let the user retry?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31999974/do-until-loop-inputbox-infinitely-loops

Comment: @Djhans26 please post a new question as this is a new issue and not in your initial question. New questions get new posts. If questions were allowed to continuously evolve, no question would ever really be answered.

Comment: Here is one more link that shows you how to do this with a date

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430765/input-box-date-range-in-vba